# How can I reset UICollectionView scroll position using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, position

I'm using a UITableView with UITableViewCells inside which within it has a UICollectionView. The first item in each UICollectionView is a header cell which I don't want to focus on.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // TODO: scroll to correct position here
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

So the furthest left I will focus on, is the first cell to the right of the header cell (at index 1). Issue that comes up is -- when scrolling right, and the cells scroll offscreen and I scroll back to the left, since I can't focus on the first item, the header cell is forever offscreen since the scroll position doesn't update. How can I update the scroll position programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line is what worked. indexPath in this case is equal to the NSIndexPath of the first cell.

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: true)
```